# When to reset the stack in mips?

Tags: assembly, mips, stack-memory

I am trying to use the stack to pass around parameters to my functions, but I am getting problems with the values passing. I never reset the stack and I am wondering if that could be the issue. The issue is I am running a sort of double loop in a way and I am not sure where I should reset. The value I am trying to save is the $a2 in the initial IsAmicable. It should be saved through the whole loop as it is the ending value of my entire loop. I am wondering if saving to the stack is my issue and if so where I would put the return stack in my code. My code is below.

```
 .data 
 sent1: .asciiz "Input the start of the range: "
 sent2: .asciiz "Input the end of the range: "
 sent4: .asciiz "IN ELSE "
 sent5: .asciiz " ," 
 

 userInput: .word 20
 userInput2: .word 20
 number: .space 20
 number2: .space 20
 
 .text
 main:
    
     # Add space on the stack for two words
 
 li $v0, 4            # Loads immediate for a sentace to be printed
 la $a0, sent1        # Loads the address of the sentance to print 
 syscall              # System calls and prints out sentance

 li $v0, 5
 syscall
 move $t1, $v0
 
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, sent2
 syscall
 
 li $v0, 5
 syscall 
 move $t2, $v0

 move $a1, $t1
 move $a2, $t2

 
 slt $s0, $a2, $a1
 bne  $s0, $zero, Else
 addi $sp, $sp, -20
 sw $a1, 0($sp)
 sw $a2, 4($sp)
 jal IsAmicable
 
 Else:
 
 move $a3, $a1
 move $a1, $a2
 move $a2, $a3
 addi $sp, $sp, -20
 sw $a1, 0($sp)
 sw $a2, 4($sp)
 
 jal IsAmicable
 
 IsAmicable:

 lw $a1, 0($sp)
 lw $a2, 4($sp)
 loop:
 #lw $a2, 4($sp)
 li $v0, 1
 move $a3, $a2
 syscall
 beq $a1, $a2, Endif    # Setup for loop from value in a1 to value in a2

 addi $a1, $a1, 1           # Adds 1 to a1 to iterate
 sw $a1, 0($sp) 
 sw $a2, 0($sp)
                      # loads value in a1 to address in a0 to pass to isFactor
 jal IsFactor

 continue:

 lw $a0, 12($sp)
 lw $a2, 4($sp)
 move $a3, $a0
 sw $a3, 12($sp)
 sw $a0, 0($sp)
 sw $a2, 4($sp)
 
 jal IsFactor2

 continue2:

 lw $t2, 0($sp)
 lw $a3, 12($sp)
 lw $a2, 4($sp)
 bne $t2, $a3, loop
 li $v0, 1
 move $a0, $a2
 syscall
 
 sw $a2, 4($sp)
 j loop
 
 
 
 IsFactor:

 lw $a1, 0($sp)
 lw $a2, 4($sp)
 move $a3, $0
 li $a3, 0

 
 loop2:

 move $t4, $zero
 addi $a3, $a3, 1
 bne $a1, $a3, continue  
 rem $t4, $a1, $a3
 bne $t4, 0,loop2
 add $a0, $a0, $a3
 sw $a0, 12($sp)
 sw $a2, 4($sp)
 j loop2
 


 Endif:

 add $sp, $sp, 20

 li $v0, 10
 syscall
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 IsFactor2:

 lw $a0, 0($sp)
 lw $a2, 4($sp)
 move $a3, $0
 li $a3, 0
 
 loop3:
 
 move $t3, $zero

 
 bgt $a3, $a0, continue2 
 addi $a3, $a3, 1 
 rem $t3, $a0, $a3
 bne $t3, 0,loop3
 add $t2, $t2, $a3
 sw $t2, 0($sp)
 sw $a2, 4($sp)
 j loop3
```

Comment: _"I am trying to use the stack to pass around parameters to my functions"_. Any particular reason for that? Normally, one would just use the `$a` registers for passing arguments to functions.

Comment: You are using `jal` as if to call a fiunction, but never use `$ra` or `jr`, so there are no functions here.

Comment: You are using `jal` but not using `$ra`, which is the only thing that makes `jal` different from `j`. You therefore are just jumping around inside one big function. You didn't write three functions.

Comment: MIPS doesn't use the stack to hold a function's return address. When you use `jal` the address after the `jal` is written to `$ra`. Then you use `jr $ra` to return to wherever you came from.